# Write math formula in python

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

[This is the value I want to calculate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8arjN.png)
I am writing it as follows, here i is the imaginary number.I am using python and networkx.Can someone help.

```
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from pylab import *
import cmath
import networkx as nx
import random as rd
import numpy as np

g=nx.karate_club_graph()
for i in g.nodes_iter():
    g.node[i]['theta']=1

a=abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in    g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())
```

## The error output that I get is:

"""File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory/bookpractice.py', wdir='C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory')

File "C:\Users\Bhawesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Bhawesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory/bookpractice.py", line 18, in 
    b=abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())

TypeError: a float is required """

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Next time, indent your code by 4 spaces to format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `sqrt` operation doesn't support negative integers. However, numpy works with complex numbers. The imaginary number $i$ is given by `1j` in Python. So you will have to convert your equation to:

```
a=abs((np.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())
```

Comment: You could also use the standard library's `cmath` module to get an `exp` function that works with complex numbers (without needing an external library like `numpy`).

Comment: Always get the following error: "TypeError: a float is required"

Comment: It probably gives a little more information than just the error message.  That information is actually relevant to figuring out what the problem is.  Please edit your question and include the full traceback.