# Writing a mathematical formula in python

Tags: python, networkx

I am writing this formula in python. [Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozo5T.png)
I am using the following code. It always gives error.

```
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from pylab import *
import cmath
import networkx as nx
import random as rd
import numpy as np


g=nx.karate_club_graph()
for i in g.nodes_iter():
    g.node[i]['theta']=1


a=abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())
```

## I get the following traceback

```
runfile('C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory/bookpractice.py', wdir='C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-9fd718b8faeb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory/bookpractice.py', wdir='C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory')

  File "C:\Users\Bhawesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Bhawesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Bhawesh/Desktop/workingdirectory/bookpractice.py", line 20, in <module>
    a=abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())

TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: Did you try adding `float` to the expression.

Comment: Yes..still gives the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write math formula in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990143/write-math-formula-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems is this:

```
a=abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(1j)) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())
```

You have 1j, this is a literal and python does not know how to execute it.

From your comments, use this:

```
sumValue = sum(cmath.exp(g.node[i]['theta'] * cmath.sqrt(-1)) for i in g.nodes_iter()) 
r = abs(sumValue/g.number_of_nodes())
```

Comment: Please post more information of what you changed and the error message you received. I was able to replicate your problem, now I am debugging it.

Comment: 1j is also not defined.

Comment: I just used j instead of 1j. Also used float with the expression so that final expression looks like:a=float(abs((cmath.exp( (g.node[i]['theta']*(j) for i in g.nodes_iter()))/g.number_of_nodes())))

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not executing the equation like you want to, to match the equation picture you posted. That equation is not correct since 1j is not defined, but try breaking it down into its pieces: sumValue = sum(cmath.exp(g.node[i]['theta']) for i in g.nodes_iter())
r = abs(sumValue/g.number_of_nodes())

Comment: I am using this code(I think it works..Thanks):sumValue = sum(cmath.exp(g.node[i]['theta'] * cmath.sqrt(-1)) for i in g.nodes_iter()) 
r = abs(sumValue/g.number_of_nodes())